# Replace the first occurrence of a pattern in a String

Tags: string, rust

I am trying to write a `replace_first()` function but I could not find the correct way to manage this.

I have the following input:

```
let input = "Life is Life".to_string();
```

I want to replace such input to following romantic output:

```
My wife is Life
```

The `replace` function replaces all the occurrences. How can I implement the `replace_first` function so I can use it like following:

```
let input = "Life is Life".to_string();
let output = input.replace_first("Life", "My wife");
println!({}, output); // Expecting the output as "My wife is life"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [replacen](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.replacen)

> Replaces first N matches of a pattern with another string.
>
> replacen creates a new String, and copies the data from this string
>   slice into it. While doing so, it attempts to find matches of a
>   pattern. If it finds any, it replaces them with the replacement string
>   slice at most count times.

```
let input = "Life is Life".to_string();
let output = input.replacen("Life", "My wife", 1);

assert_eq!("My wife is Life", output);
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6ed49516b4cb50320ecbcea987fc4728)